# Add to array/object in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to add to an object in Node:

```
exports.getAthleteData = function(accessToken, athleteId) {
    var athleteData = {};
    strava.athlete.get({'access_token': accessToken},function(err, payload) {
        athleteData.push({
            athleteName: payload.firstname + ' ' + payload.lastname,
            profile: payload.profile,
            profileMedium: payload.profile_medium,
            isPremium: payload.premium,
            sex: payload.sex
        });
    });
    return athleteData;
}
```

When calling the function I get an error `TypeError: athleteData.push is not a function`.

If I remove `.push` and do the below, all that is returned is `{}`.

```
athleteData = {
                athleteName: payload.firstname + ' ' + payload.lastname,
                profile: payload.profile,
...
```

To be sure, I dumped `payload` in the console and it gave me the JSON object I was expecting.

I'm certainly missing something very simple. This is my first foray into Node/Express and I'm really enjoying it, but I need to improve my JavaScript after years of relying on jQuery.

Comment: `athleteData` is an object. Objects don't have a `push` method - did you mean to define it as an array? `var athleteData = []` - I also worry that `strava.athlete.get` is an async method and you're returning before the call is complete.

Comment: `athleteData` is an object not an array ,it doesn't have a `push()` method.

Comment: Also, you cant return `athleteData` like that. `strava.athlete.get` is async, so you have to do a callback with `athleteData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` is an Array method. If you want `athleteData` to be an array, change its declaration:
`var athleteData = [];`

It is possible to add new keys to an object dynamically using the bracket syntax, but you need to come up with the name of the key. for example:

```
var obj = {};
var funkyKey = '1234'
obj['name'] = 'Bob';
obj['age'] = 23;
obj[funkyKey] = 'test';
console.dir(obj); // { name: 'Bob', age: 23, 1234: 'test }
```

yes, this is similar to using the dot syntax: `obj.name = 'Bob'`, but gives you more control over the name of the new key.